# Z-Index Now Allowing Link

Tags: html, css

I am building a website with a banner and a search bar at the top of the page. The bottom of the banner, by design, is supposed to go behind the search bar. I did this by using z-indexes (The banner is 0, the search bar is 1). I also want the banner to serve as a link to the home page from anywhere on the site.

My problem is that, due to the z-indexing, the banner is unclickable. When I place banner in front of the search bar, the banner is clickable and fine; but when placed behind, it is as if the  tag "followed" it and is now unusable.

Is there a way to make my banner z-index to 0, my link z-index to 1, and my search bar z-index to 2? I have tried to assign a z-index to the link (the ) separately from the image using the "style" parameter, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All elements that use the `z-index` parameter must also be positioned with the `position` parameter in CSS. My search bar was not `position`ed.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp

Answer (score 0):

Does the entire banner need to be clickable, or just the area not behind the search bar? If the entire thing doesn't need to be, you could always add a transparent layer over that portion of the banner (though this isn't really something I'd suggest and seems like a hack).

From my understanding, a negative z-index always results in an unclickable link, but that doesn't seem to be your issue. Any chance you could post some source code so we could examine it?